# Неправильно отрабатывает компонент TIdHTTP в Delphi

Tags: delphi, http, get

При парсинге **HTML** на **Delphi** заметил такой косяк, метод **GET** возвращает не весь **HTML**: когда искал нужные ноды не смог их найти в дереве **DOM**, начал исследовать и обнаружил пропажу. Если зайти на сайт и сохранить страницу ручками - разница размера с результатом **TIdHTTP** - более чем в 2 раза.
Мой код:

```
function GetWebPage(const url: string): string;
const
  agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 16_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1';
var
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  try
    SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html';
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/html';
    HTTP.Request.UserAgent := agent;
    Result := HTTP.Get(url).Trim;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
    SSL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Ответ из **HTTP.Response**:

```
ResponseCode: 200 ResponseText: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare
CacheControl: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
CharSet: utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
ContentType: text/html
TransferEncoding: chunked
GetNamePath: TIdHTTPResponse
```

Подскажите, может я где допустил ошибку, или подскажите через какой компонент (под **Delphi**) лучше делать **GET** запросы.

Comment: Попробуйте включить в браузере инструменты разработки, и посмотрите непосредственный ответ на GET-запрос. Можете очень сильно удивиться, насколько он отличается от "сохранить страницу"

Answer (score 1):

1. Вполне вероятно ты спотыкаешься о защиту Cloudflare. В интенрете ищем "web scraping cloudflare".
2. Возможно DOM модель достраивается динамически при помощи JavaScript. Попробуй в браузере сохранить страницу. (Вроде это не твой случай.)

P.S. https://habr.com/ru/articles/716434/ "Chrome Headless против cloudflare JS challenge"

Comment: я делал обычный фетч в JavaScript к этому же сайту, и мне возвращался нормальная страница, со всеми тегами (по крайне мере, которые мне нужны были в ней присутствовали), ни какой cloudflare не помешал

Comment: Попробуй другие сайты, проверь поле "TransferEncoding: chunked". Внимательно сравни ответ твоей программы и реального html, если твоя программа обрывает файл, то видимо дело в chunked. "The Content-Length header is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by '\r\n'"